# Are there supersymmetry algebras with higher spinor representations?

Tags: supersymmetry, representation-theory, spacetime-dimensions, spinors, higher-spin

The super-Poincare algebra contains supersymmetry generators $Q^I$ which satisfy fermionic anticommutation relations. By the [higher-dimensional analogue of the spin-statistics theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/455539/what-is-the-spin-statistics-theorem-in-higher-dimensions), they must transform in spinor representations of the Lorentz group. In the familiar case of $d = 3+1$, they are usually taken to be Weyl spinors, or equivalently Majorana spinors.

It seems that in general, supersymmetry generators are always taken to transform in the *minimal* spinor representation, which are Dirac, Weyl or Majorana, or Majorana-Weyl, depending on the dimension. We then usually allow for $\mathcal{N}$ supersymmetry generators, all transforming in the same way.

However, this doesn't seem to me to be the most general possibility. Why not take the SUSY generators to transform in non-minimal spinor representations? For example, in $d = 3+1$ one could take the SUSY generator to have spin $3/2$. This would change the structure of the SUSY multiplets, e.g. I would imagine they are spaced by spin $3/2$ instead of $1/2$. It could be the case that even $\mathcal{N} = 1$ SUSY with a spin $3/2$ SUSY generator would generate particles with too high helicity, but perhaps the situation is less constrained in $d < 4$?

Has this kind of SUSY been investigated, or if not, what is the issue with it?

Comment: The answer is that SUSY generators can only be spin 1/2. I gave an answer in this thread: [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/417989/is-there-a-3-2-supersymmetry/418025#418025](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/417989/)

Comment: @otillaf Does this work similarly for $d \neq 4$?

Comment: I don't know. One shoud see if Coleman-Mandula theorem works in a similar way in higher dimensions  (and I think it should work, at least in d>1+1, considering only flat spacetimes). Then you have a strong constrain on the anticommutators of SUSY generators which together SO(N) clebsch-gordan decomposition could give us the right answer. Maybe I'll try to work it later.

Comment: This is addressed by Weinberg (cf. Vol.III, page 383).